# How To Stop The JqGrid From Reload

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need To Save Data on onclickonPgButtons in jqgrid and After Saving Data  It's need To Go To Next/Prev row .Below Function was written on OnClickPgButton Function of Edit Form .

```
   jQuery("#table").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { search: false, refresh: false, del: false, add: false, cloneToTop: true }, { height: editFormheight, width: editFormwidth, reloadAfterSubmit: true, closeAfterEdit: true, recreateForm: true, cloneToTop: true,
    onclickPgButtons: function (whichbutton, formid, rowid) { ModificationDataSave(whichbutton, formid, rowid); $("#edithdtable").stop(); }
});
function ModificationDataSave(whichbutton, formid, rowid) {

if ($("#" + $("#PId").val()).closest("td").text().trim() != $("#Name").val()) {
    if (confirm('There is some unsaved data. Would you like to save?')) {
        $("#sData").trigger("click");
    }
    else {
        $("#edithdtable").stop();
    }
}
```

}

My Problem is After Saving the Data, I need to show the next/prev row in editform.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: can you specify your question? what does your html look like, where is the function called,... try to add a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: After Saving the Data into Database ..then I need to show the edit form on my page.. @Hans Vn

Comment: Maybe you can create the form but don't let it display yet (with css: display: none;). display it when you need it $("#form#).show();

Comment: okay..i will try to do it...thanks for your replay @Hans Vn

Comment: $("#form#).show();  is not working....@Hans Vn

Comment: yeah, i'm sorry, it was a type mistake... it should have been $("#form").show(); , where 'form' is the id of the form. For more information: [jquery ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Comment: $("#edithtable").show(); i was tried this only in my function ..but it's doing nothing. @Hans Vn

Comment: Are you sure the id exists? You can open your browsers error console to check the script is running correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correct your question you should just return `false` from the callback `onclickPgButtons`:

```js
onclickPgButtons: function (whichbutton, formid, rowid) {
    if (...) { // do some tests
        return false;
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**: If you need have no reload of the grid *on submit* the results you need just use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` option of form editing (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties)).

Comment: It's Not Working..the grid is reloading and Editform is Not Showing on the page.

Comment: @Ksnrg: I'm not sure that I understand correctly what you need. Look at "**UPDATED**" part of my answer.

Comment: My Process as Below way:    1)If I Change Anything in EditFormField then Click Next/Prev Button ,then i need to show popup window (confirmsave) It's contain the two things ok and cancel      2)IF I click Ok Then EditForm changes data  Saved into database (.ashx)by using the  $("#sData").trigger("click");  .then I need to go next/prev   in EDitform and I need to show the Changes in jqgrid